# Matlab mex file crashes on windows - cannot debug

Tags: matlab, runtime-error, visual-studio-debugging, mex

I have a mex-file I compiled

```
>> mex -g myMex.cpp
```

I ran it on several inputs and it works just fine.
All of a sudden, for a specific input, it crashes the machine!

Following the instructions [on how to debug using visual studio](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-c-c-language-mex-files.html) I attached the debuger to Matlab process and put a break-point at the **first** line of my `mexFunction`.

However, when I tired to debug visual studio and Matlab crashes **before** the break point is hit in the mex C++ code!

Has anyone encountered such a frustrating behavior? How can I debug this crash if the crash happens before I can stop in the debugger?

Comment: Same thing append with Win7 - MatLab 2013a. I tried to debug Mexopencv. I found nothing, so I gave up.

Comment: @AlexandreBizeau for some reason it seems like visual studio will not stop at my break points (and rather crash instead). I suspect I'm not using the correct compilation/linkage flags... I managed to find my bug in the good old comment/print/compile method :(...

Comment: @Shai: can you come up with a small reproducible case we can test? Also please state your OS, MATLAB and VS versions.. Crashing the whole machine is a very serious bug!

Comment: For me it never the same, sometime matlab crash with a segmentation error. Or nothing happen, like no break in visual studio and matlab run the code perfectly without crashing. I haven't investiged a lot on that problem. But I wonder how to do it. I solve my problem without using debugger but I'll need later on for sure.

Comment: @AlexandreBizeau: when you compile in debug mode, you will be linking against a different version of the CRT with extra checks enabled to detect memory corruptions and such errors. This usually explains the difference you're seeing when compiling with optimized vs. debug flags. As for debugging [mexopencv](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv), it usually helps to compile OpenCV from sources yourself instead of relying on the precompiled binaries provided.

Comment: @Shai: To find out the exact compilation flags used, see the file: `fullfile(prefdir,'mexopts.bat')`. In case of a crash, MATLAB will generate [crash dump](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100816) files in your `%TEMP%` folder. You should also post the relevant part from those

Comment: @Amro thank you for the comments. I'll try and see if I can provide the relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really the answer you're looking for, but due to issues similar to the one you describe I've always found *visual* debugging of Matlab MEX files so fiddly as to be more trouble than it's worth.  It may be quicker to track down problems by inserting `mexPrintf`  and/or  `return` statements in the main `mexFunction` routine.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have been working with mex-files for quite a few years and never had any issues with visual debugging. In fact, I prefer this method to any other and it troubled me a lot once that I did not have these capabilities on Linux machines as well.